# Merging two adjacent polygons which borders are not touching each other?

Tags: polygon, vector, merge

I want to merge adjacent single polygons which are apart from each other.

**Important note:** I cannot use ArcGIS, I need to do this programatically, in any language (R, Python, Ruby, PostGIS) doesn't really matter which it is, it can be a combination of a scripting or compiled code and/or command line tools.

So far I have tried using Turf.js methods convex (hull) and union. Union doesn't grow/shrink the edges to to complete with the neighbouring polygon, but it rather just creates a a geometry collection of all the polygons processed as a single feature. The convex hull creates a single polygon but ignores the inner points, just the farthest and gives a wrong final shape. I've tried using the **Eliminate Sliver Polygons...** in the QGIS **Vector>Geoprocessing Tools** menu but the operation fails with a Python error: **

> global name 'QErrorMessage' is not defined
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/qgis-214/2.14.1/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doEliminate.py", line 96, in accept
>       self.eliminate(inLayer, boundary, self.progressBar, outFileName)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/qgis-214/2.14.1/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doEliminate.py", line 236, in eliminate
>       QErrorMessage(self).showMessage(
>   NameError: global name 'QErrorMessage' is not defined

**3 Adjacent polygons that are suppose to be merged into a single one:**

### [image: **3 Polygons that are suppose to be merged into a single one**]

**Desired resulting single polygon shape**
The expected border is drawn with a red contour.

[image: **Desired resulting single polygon shape**]

Comment: Concave hull might work. Have a look at these http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concave-hull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo solution with OpenJUMP

Original polygons

[image]

Buffer the polygons so much that they overlap and make a union. This can be done as a single operation with OpenJUMP. Flat end cap and mitre join with quite a high limit are good settings.

[image]

The gaps between the polygons have disappeared but the union is too large.

[image]

Use negative buffer for the union and shrink it. Red outline shows the final result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As your original question was about an automated/scripted solution... you could try  the [dissolve_within_distance](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/geofileops.dissolve_within_distance.html#geofileops.dissolve_within_distance) feature of [geofileops](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io).

```
import logging
import geofileops as gfo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Init logging so progress printed by gfo is shown
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    input_path = "/path/you/like/zones.gpkg"
    output_path = "/path/you/like/zones_dissolved.gpkg"
    gfo.dissolve_within_distance(
        input_path=input_path, output_path=output_path, distance=10
    )
```

Disclaimer: I am the developer of [geofileops](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io).